# Ensure parent only displays when all childs are loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am very new to react and I'm struggling with the following. I created a form in react and that form contains a dropdown. I need to reuse that dropdown in multiple pages so I thought to make it a component that is fully responsible to get all data.

In the form component I get all data and one of those fields is the selectedServerDataId. The selectId field contains the ID of the value that needs to be selected in the dropdown.

```
<snip includes/>

class Arrival extends React.PureComponent {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            formData: {}
        };
    }

   async componentDidMount() {
        await fetch(urls.addEditUrl)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ formData: data });
            });
    }

    <snip some setstate helpers/>

    render() {
        const { formData } = this.state;
        return (
                <Form >
                <Selector label="select"
                    onChange={this.UpdateFormSelectData.bind(this, 'selectedServerDataId')}
                    value={formData.selectedServerDataId}/>
                <DateItem label="date"
                          allowClear={true}
                          value={formData.date}
                          onChange={this.updateFormDateData.bind(this, 'date')}/>
                <snip more fields.../>
            </Form>);
    }
}

export default Arrival;
```

The fetch in the parent component retrieves the data for the edit form including the selectedServerDataId. My child component looks like below:

```
<snip usings />

class ServerDataSelector extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            options: [],
        };
    }

    async componentDidMount() {
        await fetch(URLS.GetServerData)
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(data => {
                this.setState({ options: data });
            });
    }

    render() {
        const { options } = this.state;
        return (
            <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label={t(this.props.label)} >
                <Select setValue={this.props.onChange} getValue={() => this.props.value} selectedOption={this.props.value} name={this.props.label}>
                        {options.map(d => <Option key={d.id} value={d.id}>{d.value}</Option>)}
                </Select>
                  //TODO add model window to manipulate list.
                </FormItem>);
    }
}

export default ServerDataSelector 
ServerDataSelector { Selector }
```

Currently when the page renders I first see the ID of the selected value in the dropdown and a split second later I see the actual selected value label.

Is there a way to ensure that the parent component only renders when the childs are completely done loading?

Answer (score 0):

The main issue you have here is that you have two components that have a strict rendering hierarchical relationship (parent -> child) but equal data fetching responsibility.

This leads to the situation where you have to react to data retrieval between multiple components in a specific order and is a non-trivial concurrency problem. One solution would be to use a shared state container (using [Redux](https://redux.js.org/) or the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)) and have both components save their results into this shared state bucket and then whenever the bucket has all the data, you present it (until then you can show a spinner for example).

A simpler solution would be to just move the fetching into one of the components, eliminate this split data-fetching responsibility altogether, and allow the component fetching the data to also control the rendering.

One way is to get all the data in the parent and have the child just be a pure component that is rendered when the data is received:

```
class Arrival extends React.Component {
  // ...

  async componentDidMount() {
    const [formData, options] = await Promise.all([
      fetch(urls.addEditUrl).then(response => response.json()),
      fetch(URLS.GetServerData).then(response => response.json())
    ]);

    this.setState({ formData, options });
  }

  render() {
    const { formData, options } = this.state;
    return (
      <Form>
        {/* ... */}
        {formData &&
          options && (
            <Selector
              label="select"
              options={this.state.options}  {/* pass the options here */}
              onChange={this.UpdateFormSelectData.bind(
                this,
                "selectedServerDataId"
              )}
              value={formData.selectedServerDataId}
            />
          )}
      </Form>
    );
  }
}
```

`Selector` is now only a presentational component, no need for state:

```
const ServerDataSelector = props => (
  <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label={t(this.props.label)}>
    <Select
      setValue={this.props.onChange}
      getValue={() => this.props.value}
      selectedOption={this.props.value}
      name={this.props.label}
    >
      {this.props.options.map(d => (     {/* use props.options */}
        <Option key={d.id} value={d.id}>
          {d.value}
        </Option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  </FormItem>
);
```

You could optionally show a spinner or a loading indicator:

```
...
{
  formData && options ? (
    <Selector
      label="select"
      onChange={this.UpdateFormSelectData.bind(this, "selectedServerDataId")}
      options={this.state.options}
      value={formData.selectedServerDataId}
    />
  ) : (
    <Spinner />
  );
}
```

Alternatively, you can have the child fetch all the data and the parent would just render the child.

```
class ServerDataSelector extends React.Component {
  // ...

  async componentDidMount() {
    const [formData, options] = await Promise.all([
      fetch(urls.addEditUrl).then(response => response.json()),
      fetch(URLS.GetServerData).then(response => response.json())
    ]);

    this.setState({
      value: formData.selectedServerDataId,
      options
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label={t(this.props.label)}>
        <Select
          setValue={this.props.onChange}
          getValue={() => this.state.value}  {/* use the value from the state */}
          selectedOption={this.state.value}  {/* use the value from the state */}
          name={this.props.label}
        >
          {this.state.options.map(d => (
            <Option key={d.id} value={d.id}>
              {d.value}
            </Option>
          ))}
        </Select>
      </FormItem>
    );
  }
}
```

You could also add a spinner within the child to prevent page jank and allow for a nicer UX:

```
render() {
  if (!this.state.value || !this.state.options) {
    return <Spinner />;
  }

  return (
    <FormItem {...formItemLayout} label={t(this.props.label)}>
      <Select
        setValue={this.props.onChange}
        getValue={() => this.state.value}
        selectedOption={this.state.value}
        name={this.props.label}
      >
        {this.state.options.map(d => (
          <Option key={d.id} value={d.id}>
            {d.value}
          </Option>
        ))}
      </Select>
    </FormItem>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. Your answer makes me think I try to do things with react in a way that is not react way. As a backend programmer I always try to make components that are reusable and have 1 responsibility. Ill will take a look at the libraries provided, but otherwise ill go with the parent loads all route. Although I hope I will find a way to handle this, because that could save me a lot of frontend code in the application I’m making.

Comment: Glad to help mate. Components in react should be reusable, your idea is correct. Having anything with 1 responsibility is a solid software engineering principle, regardless of the technology section (backend, frontend, etc.). I strongly agree with you on all these points. The only issue you have in your approach is where you drew the component border. My suggestion here is based on the small code sample you gave but the best advice I got is to take your idea about reusability and single-responsibility and wiggle your component design a bit :)

Comment: This indeed is a small piece of code. The data component will be a dropdown that in the end will have an add button next to it that will open a model window to add a new item to the dropdown. Currently working on an idea that seems to work, but not yet there ;) Will share that part of the code also.

Answer (score 0):

After many tries and errors I found a way to fix this.

In my parent state I added the following object:

```
this.state = {
            formData: null,
            loadedComponents: {
                parentComponentIsLoaded: false,
                childComponent1IsLoaded: false,
                childComponent2IsLoaded: false,
            }
        };
```

Then I added the following 2 methods in my parent

```
   componentLoaded = (field, data) => {
    const { loadedComponents } = this.state;
    var fieldName = field + "IsLoaded";

    this.setState({ loadedComponents: { ...loadedComponents, [fieldName]: true } });
}

allComponentsLoaded() {

    const { loadedComponents } = this.state;
    console.log(loadedComponents);
    for (var o in loadedComponents) {
        if (!loadedComponents[o]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Changed the render method to this:

```
        return (
        formData ?
            <Form className={this.allComponentsLoaded() ? '' : 'hidden'} >
                <ChildComponet1 {someprops} isLoaded={this.componentLoaded}/>
                <ChildComponent2 {someprops} isLoaded={this.componentLoaded}/>
            <snip />
        </Form> : <div />);
```

And added the following line in the childs componentDidMount method after the fetching of the data.

```
this.props.isLoaded('childComponet1', true)
```

Maybe this is very bad react design and should you actually use MEM035's answer, but it does work